# How to get the maximum value of a key in dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to get the URL of a video with maximum resolution.

If I had the following dictionary, would it be easiest to get the URL of the video with the maximum size?

Is it best to split the size by partition, format the number into an int type, and then get the value?

```
videos = {
        'size_476_306': 'https://www.....',
        'size_560_360': 'https://www.....',
        'size_644_414': 'https://www.....',
        'size_720_480': 'https://www.....',
}
```

**Solved**

I couldn't figure out lambda, so I implemented it in a different way.

```
for size, v_url in videos.items():

    max_size_info = size.split('_')
    split_size = int(max_size_info[1])
    size_array.append(split_size)
    video_array.append(v_url)

max_size = size_array.index(max(size_array))
if str(size_array[max_size]) in v_url:
    print(size,v_url)
```

Comment: Do the dimensions always have the same number of digits (as they do in your examples), or can there be four digit sizes, like `size_1920_1080` or similar? If the numeric parts of your strings are all the same length as each other, a lexicographical string comparison will match numeric comparisons, so you probably won't need to do any parsing. If the numbers can vary in length, then you probably do need to do the parsing.

Comment: @Blckknght. I beg to differ. Which is bigger, `500_100` or `499_999`?

Comment: That's a domain specific thing. Maybe the questioner only cares about one of the dimensions. All the examples have similar aspect ratios (the first three are exactly the same), and it's quite reasonable to expect that for multiple different versions of the same video. If it is reliably consistent throughout their data and they don't expect larger sizes with four digits, then sorting the strings naively will work just fine.

Comment: It's very reasonable for a video to be either under or over 1000 pixels in either dimension.  Baking in an assumption about the number of digits seems like a recipe for disaster to me.

Comment: I'm not interested in the dimensions, I only needed to get the maximum resolution video, so I modified the code.Thanks

Comment: Please don't put the solution in the question. Instead, you can [answer your own question](/help/self-answer).

Comment: @donbe take a look at my updated answer for a simpler approach than what you've got here (and hopefully easier to understand than my quick one-liner) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it best to split the size by partition, format the number into an int type, and then get the value?

Yes, that's the way I'd do it:

```
>>> max(videos.items(), key=lambda i: int.__mul__(*map(int, i[0].split("_")[1:])))
('size_720_480', 'https://www.....')
```

Here's a slightly more verbose version with a named function:

```
>>> def get_resolution(key: str) -> int:
...     """
...     Gets the resolution (as pixel area) from 'size_width_height'.
...     e.g. get_resolution("size_720_480") -> 345600
...     """
...     _, width, height = key.split("_")
...     return int(width) * int(height)
...
>>> max(videos, key=get_resolution)
'size_720_480'
```

Given that expression that gives us the largest key, we can easily get the corresponding value:

```
>>> videos[max(videos, key=get_resolution)]
'https://www.....'
```

or we could get the key, value pair by taking the max of `items()`, here using a much simpler `lambda` that just translates `key, value` into `get_resolution(key)`:

```
>>> max(videos.items(), key=lambda i: get_resolution(i[0]))
('size_720_480', 'https://www.....')
```

Comment: Too much logic for a one-liner, imo.

Comment: The alternatives people presented caused me actual physical pain, so I did my own more verbose version.

Comment: Version without the lambda, much better!